# Motion Tracking: Tracking Ball in relation to a court

Tags: android, google-project-tango, motion, motion-detection

I am an app developer for a tennis training app. For each of the questions, we will assume that the mobile device is stationary.

1. If the mobile device is stationary, does Tango have the capability to track a ball and target in relation to a court? If so, How accurate and reliable can this capability be?
2. Does Tango have the capability to see the out of bounds lines of the court and record if the ball goes out of bounds or not? If so, How accurate and reliable can this capability be?

Answer (score 1):

1. Tango doesn't provide object tracking. Also, in your case, tennis balls are too far away for depth sensor to pick up and track.
2. This is not very feasible as of today. First, Tango's depth sensor range is from 0.5m to 4m. Thus, the tennis balls are probably going to be out of range for the depth sensor to pick up. Also, Tango's motion tracking has 1% drift over distance device travelled, it might be hard for it to accurately measure out court boundary over time.